# How to bypass the open file security warning as part of start command in batch?

Tags: batch-file

SSASDiag is a diagnostics tool by Microsoft. however, its not something install-able and you have to open up the exe everytime to run it. currently i have the exe saved in a folder location, and instead of having to cd every time there and start up the exe, i am writing a small bat file that i would pin to the taskbar with the following command:

```
start /d "N:\Windows2019 Sandbox stuff\SSASDiag" SSASDiag.exe
```

it pops up the following:

[image: sfdsadsa]

is there a force start switch or something i can use to bypass this popup?

Note: i have to use start command because when i double click on the exe, i think the UNC does not allow popups because nothing seems to open up unless i start the exe from cmd.

Comment: Have you tried, [this method](https://www.technipages.com/fix-we-cant-verify-who-created-this-file-error/amp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rightclick the file and click on properties.

There should be a `Security` segment(under `General`)

In this segment, just tick `Unblock`

After that, just confirm it with `Apply` and `Ok`.

[image: image with the dialoge]

Comment: but isnt there a way to do this as part of the start command? so that it can be dynamic for any files i may have in future

Comment: You could download it with `curl` or use the powershell `Unblock-File` command.

Comment: download the command with curl? could you elaborate, im intrigued

Comment: I mean download the file with curl(so that it won't get blocked) **or** use the `Unblock-File` command to unblock the file.

Comment: ok...i understand unblock-file for powershell, ive used it before, but im curious about the curl option. im confused why would i download the file with curl? what does that have to do with unblocking the file?

Comment: If you download a file with `curl` and redirect the output to a new file, the downloaded file will not be blocked.